# Magento backend translation to Dutch language

Tags: magento-1.7

How to translate Magento admin section (only admin section ) by default its in English.I need to translate it to Dutch language.

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-translate-form-labels-in-magentos-admin-area/) you may have to download a csv of translation labels by the looks of it

you might also be interested in [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-dutch-translation-8713.html) but it might translate the whole site.